# Powershell : sqlcmd error handling with multiple files

Tags: powershell, sqlcmd

We have folder with multiple sql files. How to catch error with particular file and log it that file name.

We are using following script to execute sqlcmd.

```
$ServerName=$args[0]
$DatabaseName=$args[1]
$UserName=$args[2]
$Passcode=$args[3]
$FolderPath=$args[4]
$errorpath=$args[5]

foreach ($f in Get-ChildItem -path  $FolderPath -Filter *.sql | sort-object) {
    $fileCurrent = $f.fullname
     try { 
         invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerName -Database $DatabaseName -U  $UserName  -P $Passcode -InputFile $f.fullname 
}
catch {
   $_ | Out-File $errorpath -Append
}
```

}

we have 100 files in that folder and two files are erroring out we want to log error and file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't hitting the catch block, it's because you are encountering a "non-terminating" error.  Non-terminating errors don't trigger catch blocks.

To force your error to be terminating, you can either pass `-ErrorAction 1` to `Invoke-SQLCmd` or before the loop, set `$errorActionPreference = 'Stop'`.

With this change, your catch block should now be triggered when `Invoke-SQLCmd` fails.

Comment: Ya thanks man  after adding $errorActionPreference = 'Stop'  now its coming to catch block

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  ...
} catch {
  "{0}: {1}" -f ($fileCurrent, $_) | Out-File $errorpath -Append
}
```

Comment: we are getting error like this  but   here there  is  no file path and its not logging to $errorpath too                         Invoke-Sqlcmd : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'.
A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.At C:\psscripts\ip.ps1:15 char:22
+         invoke-sqlcmd <<<<  -ServerInstance $ServerName -Database $DatabaseName -U  $UserName  -P $Passcode -InputFile $f.fullname 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

Comment: One more thing  its not even goin to catch block when debugging

Comment: Does the script continue despite the error? If so, try setting `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"`.

Comment: It will continue   we want that  one

Comment: yes after adding this $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"  it comes to catch block  thanks